# extract data from text file

Tags: command-line, bash

I have text file having result output like below, I only need mapping filepath name  and Total number seqs written from this text file, please suggest how I can get this data in separate text file.

```
Input file paths

**Mapping filepath: map_leaf_M_BAN.AC.txt** (md5: a746e6e6227fafebc545d7a7e107d55c)

Sequence read filepath: leaf-45_S51_L001.m150-p1.join.fq (md5: 
8753a0afe8b89d7768e911142a1536fe)

Quality filter results

Total number of input sequences: 32992

Barcode not in mapping file: 0

Read too short after quality truncation: 682

Count of N characters exceeds limit: 0

Illumina quality digit = 0: 0

Barcode errors exceed max: 0

Result summary (after quality filtering)

Median sequence length: 273.00

LMBANAC 32310


**Total number seqs written       32310**
```

---

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Simple piplines and text tools will do the job:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ grep -E -o 'Mapping filepath: [^*]+' Data.file | cut "-d " -f3
map_leaf_M_BAN.AC.txt
             # Note the following regexp is fixed below - user's file had a TAB
walt@bat:~(0)$ grep -E -o 'Total number seqs written +[0-9]+' Data.file | awk '{print $5}'
32310
```

Since the file contains a `TAB` character (from the comment),

```
$ grep "Total number seqs written" split_library_log.txt | cat -t 
Total number seqs written^I32992 
Total number seqs written^I38519
```

The second `grep` command should be

```
 grep -E -o 'Total number seqs written[[:space]]+[0-9]+' Data.file | awk '{print $5}'
```

Of course, read `man grep;man cut;man awk;man 7 regex`.

Comment: grep -E -o 'Total number seqs written +[0-9]+' Data.file | awk '{print $5}'     # this command is not working.

Comment: How is it "not working"? When I copied your data to `Data.file` on my Ubuntu 16.04.5 system, both examples worked, see above.

Comment: Yes, you are right , this is working with the above example but I do have 150 data like above and it is not working with that file. only Mapping filepath is working.

Comment: Again, I request that you show how it's "not working". Cat you `cat -t` the line?

Comment: I did not get what should be the input in cat -t?

Comment: Look at the nonprinting characters. Do `grep "Total number seqs written" Data.file | cat -t`

Comment: [3052771@node036(kelvin) whole_its_repeat]$ grep "Total number seqs written" split_library_log.txt | cat -t
Total number seqs written^I32992
Total number seqs written^I38519           all are printed like this

Comment: The answer to my repeated question "How is it not working" is "`grep` matches no lines". Had you responded to my initial question, the solution would have been quicker. Help us help you.

Comment: Yes, grep command do not match any line....it do not show any error as well... instead of awk can we use any other command.